# Where does my newly created Form1 exist in VB Class hierarchy?

Tags: vb.net, class, hierarchy

Form1 is declared as a class, but since it inherits a bunch of stuff. I was wondering what it inherits from?

But, if it inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form, why would it have a property called "parent" from System.Web.UI.Control?

How does this all work?

P.S. Can I refer to the class Form1 in a full path way? (ex. System. sth.....)

Comment: Um, last I checked, it's [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx) property is inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, not `System.Web.UI.Control`. And you seem to be confusing inheritance with namespaces. They're not related in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- System.Object
- System.MarshalByRefObject
- System.ComponentModel.Component
- System.Windows.Forms.Control
- System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl
- System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl
- System.Windows.Forms.Form
- Some.Your.Namespace.Form1

This is full inheritance hierarchy form your `Form1` class. You can see those things in msdn. I suggest you start with article about [Form class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx).